# How does a computer chip read code, interpret it, and convert it into action?

Tags: computer-architecture

I understand that binary is effectively functioning as a “virtual representation” of low voltage and high voltage. However, I do not understand how the instruction set to MAKE the voltage high or low is being executed. Within a computer, what is physically happening to change a circuit to a “high voltage state” or a “low voltage state”?

This is presumably the lowest level instruction set that exists within computers...and I’m not quite sure I understand how it is being implemented. What is making the circuit change between high and low voltage states...and, moreover, how are these instructions designed to ENACT such a change in voltage state actually being carried out?

This is like the “instruction set that proceeds all other instruction sets”...or the “instruction set that exists BEFORE binary instruction sets can even be formed”. How does one program a circuit to do something before a programming language even exists?

In other words: How does a computer chip convert the "text" or bits that make up the program into action? How does it read the code, decide what the code is saying, and then act on what the code is saying?

Comment: Start by learning about `logic gates`.  At present you do not have a *specifically answerable* question within the rules of this site - Stack Exchange is not intended to be a general instructional reference, but only to handle specific narrow problems.

Comment: I am confused as to why this is not answerable. For example, i imagine that the pressure on a keyboard letter is responsible for initiating the voltage switches in the circuits that effectively convey that “this letter has been pressed”.

Comment: This is unanswerable because it is absurdly broad, and you have made *no effort to research* the way this actually happens in computational machinery, a subject that has been extensively documented online and off for a generation or two now.  Again, **Stack Exchange is not intended to be a first reference or general source of instruction**, but only for *specific problems*.  I would refer you to the earlier suggestion to start your journey of *self-guided discovery* by learning about **logic gates**, then general combinatorial logic, synchronous logic, state machines, and programmed machines.

Comment: Within the computer will be RAILS some at logic ZERO and some at logic ONE. Usually these are the same as GROUND and VDD, thus very conveniently when a ZERO or ONE is required, the nearby power return and power source wires can be used. This does not work for classic Motorola ECL.

Comment: "for a generation or two now".  Lessee.  The Turing Machine was born in 1936, or about , and a "generation" is about 20-30 years.  So make that three, if you count babies.  Certainly there are college kids today whose great grandparents were born at the same time or after Turing was in 1912 -- so again, three generations.

Comment: I fail to see the broadness of this question. I’m effectively asking how the computer knows to pass or not pass current through a transistor at the initiation of computer-user interaction. For the keyboard, it makes sense because presumably the physical force of button pressing serves as the conversion of mechanical energy into electrical energy. However, when I run software, is it simply my “clicking of the mouse” that functions as the mechanical energy to initiate this whole process?

Comment: You fail to see the broadness because you have no idea that you are asking for at least a half semester's worth of course material...  When you have come through personal study to understand the subject, you will see quite clearly that it could not be addressed within the bounds of Stack Exchange.  You have to crawl before you can walk, and walk before you can run.  Again, start with logic gates... engineering is very much built up of pieces made of earlier pieces.

Comment: They are not "instructed" per se.  At the level of high and low voltages, it's all logic gates.

Comment: @S.Cramer Your question is broad. You just don't know how broad it is because you don't know how deep it goes. If you don't know how a transistor can act as a switch, and two a few transistors can form a logic gate, there's no point in us continuing. You have to look that up first and you will be halfway there to answering your question.

Comment: I believe I know how transistors form a logic gate. The inquiry has to do with how the current input is initiated at the first part of the logic gate networks.

Comment: @S.Cramer That sentence is incoherent to me. I'm not sure what you're trying to ask unless you're just asking how a transistor opens or closes when you send an electrical signal into it.

Comment: One of the very best books to buy on what I perceive as your current inquiry area is "Bebop BYTES Back: An Unconventional Guide to Computers," by Clive Maxfield. (If my memory is serving me.) That addresses the internals of an MCU. Another, focused on the externals supporting a micro and well written, is Don Lancaster's two-volume "Micro Cookbook" set. For the operating system end of things, I'd recommend Douglas Comer's original (red binding) "XINU" book, circa 1983 or so. All of these target self-teaching. All are quite *accessible*.

Comment: @S.Cramer Also see [Warren's "Crazy Small CPU" based upon 7400 series parts](https://minnie.tuhs.org/Programs/CrazySmallCPU/). If you download [version 0.23 of "Digital"](https://github.com/hneemann/Digital/releases/tag/v0.23), you not only can get an easy-to-run version but you can quickly run a small program on that CPU, too. You will also find von Neumann and Harvard processors in another subdirectory of Digital. So there's lots to study there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Opcode** - the unique identifier for each possible instruction that a computer can run. Physically, it is a unique string of binary bits which is represented in Assembler as a token (so a human can read it without memorizing a string of ones and zeroes)

**Program** - a bunch of ones and zeroes (or low and high electrical signals) consisting of the sequence of opcodes and their arguments (numbers) to be executed when the system runs.

**Opcode circuitry** - the physical manifestation of the opcode. It is circuitry that reads the appropriate arguments that it will operate with or on from the instruction register, processes them, and loads the result somewhere. Each opcode has one and the this circuitry will processes the data and delivers the result into a register somewhere.

**Instruction Register** - the register that stores the instruction line which is about to be parsed and read/decoded/translated. It is loaded from wherever the program counter register is pointing at in the bits that form the program memory

**Instruction Decoder** - this circuitry reads the opcode ID field in the instruction register and sends a signal to activate the appropriate opcode circuitry which results in execution of the opcode.

It's basically a giant comparison engine with output signals to trigger each opcode. One way to imagine it is as an array of multi-bit comparators with each comparator having an output to trigger one of the opcode circuits. Each comparator examines the bits in the field of the instruction register that represents the opcode ID and compares it against a fixed value which is the bits for the opcode ID it is responsible for. If it matches, it fires a signal to the opcode circuitry to trigger it.

Or you can imagine it as a giant lookup table that takes the bits in the opcode ID field of the instruction register as an input. It's output consist of one signal line going to each opcode circuit to trigger it. The lookup table is such that only one signal line is active for any given valid input (after all, you don't want a single opcode to end up triggering two opcode circuits to run. That just doesn't make sense.)

The decoder also reads the bits in the fields of the instruction register that represent the arguments for that opcode and passes them on to the opcode circuitry so it knows what it is working with. It is a crazy, chip spanning network of signals.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98241/discussion-on-answer-by-dknguyen-how-does-a-computer-chip-read-code-interpret-i).  Any conclusions reached should be edited back into the question and/or any answer(s).

Answer (score 7):

In order to understand how to build a computer, engineers divide its operation into layers, to limit the complexity. Each layer relies on the operation of the layer 'below' to provide services to it, and provides services to the layer above. When a designer is working on a design, he usually only thinks within one layer. Each layer will have a different vocabulary.

The fact that you've used 'instruction set', 'voltage' and 'high' in the same sentence means you're trying to think across several layers at once, which we just don't do. It's not only too complex, it's meaningless.

At the very bottom layer is semiconductor physics, where we have voltages, currents, electric fields in semiconductor materials. We build transistors to make controllable switches. That's the service to the next layer up, switches. We have over the years used many different types of things to make switches, CMOS FETs, bipolar transistors, relays, you can even use compressed air. But they all make switches.

The next layer uses the switches to control voltage levels, which we call high and low, and make logic. We've forgotten all about voltage by now. If there's a 3.3v rail, anything above 2.2v counts as 'high'. We connect the switches together to make logic gates, like NAND or an inverter.

The next layer uses these logic gates to make functions. Two NAND gates cross connected can make a memory cell. A bunch of those together can make a register. Many registers together with a tree of gates to make a decoder can make a memory. Another tree of gates can make an ALU. We've generally stopped thinking about individual highs and lows, and instead individual signals tend to be 'active' or 'inactive'. Groups of signals tend to have a collective meaning. Where we have several signals in parallel, let's say 8 of them, it's too much effort to keep thinking of them as '01100001', so we call it '0x31' (hexadecimal representation), and call it a 'word'.

The next layer is where we connect these functions together, and have an ALU, with a memory, and a bank of registers.

We have done experiments recently to grow these things genetically, throw a bunch of this stuff into an FPGA, see if it works, iterate, rinse and repeat. We sometimes get interesting results. But the 'design' is totally incomprehensible.

In order to get something we can understand and design, we simplify hugely, and define parts of the design. A single register will be a 'program counter', which will point into the current place in our 'program', a list of 'instructions' that we'll execute. This gets the name 'PC'. These are our concepts, injected into the situation to give meaning. In order to make the 'instruction' ADD B work, we need to have an adder section in the ALU, which gets enabled when the ADD instruction gets decoded. We choose a small pattern of highs and lows in the instruction word, let's say '1001', say this means 'add', design the decoder to only output an active signal when it's fed with '1001', and drive that to the ALU's adder. We pick another part of the instruction word, the address, in this case the B register, and give that an encoding, and use that to drive the input multiplexer for where the adder gets its source (I've chosen a single address instruction as common on 8080, which implies a single register, the accumulator or ACC as the other source address and the result destination, other machines also use zero address (stack based), two or three address (more flexible instructions).

We go through inventing more instructions with suitable encodings to make them work, naming the registers to make them easier to remember.

Now we have a programmable MCU. All we have to do is set the bits of the memory to represent the opcodes we want to execute. This is how very old computers were programmed. You had a bunch of switches on the front, and you'd have two people, one reading from a written list of instructions, 'set address 0x34B' to data '0x21', and the other one waggling the switches to set the memory. I had my first job in 1974, and I was one of those people, loading a 13 word program into a PDP-something-or-other that we still had running in the lab.

Obviously that's not scalable, so amongst the first programs written were program loaders, assemblers, editors, to automate that process.

Comment: I didn't realize the first computers were like that where instructions were manually selected and entered during run-time. I had always assumed they were made to run their instructions on their own, but I guess that makes sense very early on since that's basically what a hand calculator is.

Comment: @DKNguyen That 13 word program was a pre-bootloader that told the computer where its paper tape reader was, so it could read its bootloader in from tape. The machine was so old, they'd rejected the idea of buying a 'ROM-tray' to keep those 13 instructions, and just roped the youngest employee in to switching it in on the odd occasions it needed to be started from scratch.

Comment: when we really crashed our PDP11 in the Test Department, we'd key in the bootloader by hand. The octal codes were taped to the  console. Once bootloader was entered, we'd press "start" and the entire operating system was read in from mylar (holes punched in it) tape.

Answer (score 2):

You ask: "I’m effectively asking how the computer knows to pass or not pass current through a transistor at the initiation of computer-user interaction."

It doesn't know.

When the blob of transistors and wires powers up, often the gates are driven to a random level (definitely high or low) by gain or feedback circuits.  Then something (another specialized circuit) pulls on a reset line, which inputs a known voltage into enough logic gates sufficient to force other important logic gate outputs and state registers into a sufficiently known state (high or low) to start hunting for and executing instructions.

From there, it mostly just logic gates converting combinations of highs and lows (often vast amounts) into other combinations of highs and lows, which moves state machines along some sequential paths.  That's what transistors wired up into logic gates do.

The state machine states, the software instruction machine codes, and any I/O inputs, are themselves are just more inputs into this mass of logic gates, which are already producing highs and lows (again, in vast amounts).

How does some particular output become high?  Read Boole, Shannon, Turing, Von Neumann, Hennessy and Patterson, and CMOS logic circuit design (too big to fit all that in this tiny box), and it can sometimes involve billions of instructions, billions of state transitions, and billions of transistors.